# Issue in renew-authorisation of stream analytics output for datalake store

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to set up (deploy) a stream analytics job with data lake store as output using terraform. Terraform internally call the Azure API (through Azure Go SDK) for stream analytics to set the datalake store output that expects a refresh token.

As per the API documentation, it is recommended to put a dummy string value here when creating the data source and then going to the Azure Portal to authenticate the data source which will update this property with a valid refresh token. Hence, I passed a "dummy" string as refresh token, and I could see the datalake store in the outputs of stream analytics. This is also referred here: [Stream Analytics Job -> DataLake ouput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948568/stream-analytics-job-datalake-ouput).

However, when when I try to renew-authroisation in the portal to set the actual refresh token, the `save` button is not seen to be enabled. Without clicking on save, we cannot update the refresh token.

I tried the same with a completely separate stream analytics job created through portal and a data-lake store output, and came across the same situation.

I could get this working (its a hack) by changing some parameters such as "format" in the output properties, and the save button is enabled. This allowed to renew-authorisation.

This could be a UI bug. Have anyone come across the situation before? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, it may be a bug in the form validation logic, I'll report this to our portal team for investigation.

Comment: Confirmed this is Portal bug and we are making a fix.